# ExceptionInInitializerError while initializing axis2 to client in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, apache-axis, soap-client

I have created a service client as standalone in eclipse and initializing the stub as below,

```
CustomerInteractionStub interaction_stub = new CustomerInteractionStub (END_POINT_URL);
```

but getting following error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisDescription.<init>(AxisDescription.java:72)
at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.<init>(AxisService.java:323)
at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.<init>(AxisService.java:394)
at com.ril.jio.www.integration.services.inventory.customerinteractionmanagement.CustomerInteractionMaintenanceStub.populateAxisService(CustomerInteractionMaintenanceStub.java:43)
at com.ril.jio.www.integration.services.inventory.customerinteractionmanagement.CustomerInteractionMaintenanceStub.<init>(CustomerInteractionMaintenanceStub.java:131)
at com.ril.jio.www.integration.services.inventory.customerinteractionmanagement.CustomerInteractionMaintenanceStub.<init>(CustomerInteractionMaintenanceStub.java:119)
at com.ril.jio.www.integration.services.inventory.customerinteractionmanagement.CustomerInteractionMaintenanceStub.<init>(CustomerInteractionMaintenanceStub.java:166)
at CSVReader1.getIRequestXML(CSVReader1.java:340)
at CSVReader1.main(CSVReader1.java:235)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.crimson.tree.ElementNode.getAttributeNodeNS(ElementNode.java:415)
at org.apache.crimson.tree.ElementNode.getAttributeNS(ElementNode.java:392)
at org.apache.axiom.locator.ImplementationFactory.parseImplementation(ImplementationFactory.java:114)
at org.apache.axiom.locator.ImplementationFactory.parseDescriptor(ImplementationFactory.java:87)
at org.apache.axiom.locator.DefaultOMMetaFactoryLocator.<init>(DefaultOMMetaFactoryLocator.java:66)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory.<clinit>(OMAbstractFactory.java:95)
... 9 more
```

Searched a lot but didnt get any solution.  Any help is appreciated. If any extra information is required, please ask and I will endeavor to provide it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace indicates that you are using Apache Crimson. That is an old DOM implementation and should no longer be used. Simply removing the corresponding JAR should resolve the problem.